# How to run a worker (continuously) on Azure App Service

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm running a Django app on Azure App Service and planning to use django-background-tasks (or Django-Q) to run background tasks.

Whichever I choose, I will need to run some sort of workers after deploying the app to Azure.

For django-background-tasks, I will need to run
`python manage.py process_tasks`

For Django Q, I will need to run
`python manage.py qcluster`

And this is all fine if I run it from my computer's command prompt, but what about App Service? Is there anyway I keep these workers running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use App Service Web Jobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Comment: But it isn’t available on a Linux App Service Plan is it?

Comment: Yes that is correct it is not supported on the Linux App Service plan.  The App Service hosting environment was not provided in the original question.    For App Services on  Linux here are some ideas to research/explore:   Custom Startup Script/File Configuration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04)   OR  Use a Custom Linux Container Image which then has your scripts loaded and executed in the background.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container